# JQuery doesn't select and change the state of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

This is the html:

```
<div class="btn btn-stock-report" id="superman">
    Superman <input type="checkbox" name="superman" />
</div>
```

this is the JQuery:

```
$('#superman').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).children('input:checkbox:first').is(':checked')) {
        superman = true;
        $(this).children('input:checkbox:first').removeAttr('checked');
    }
    else {
        superman = false;
        $(this).children('input:checkbox:first').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
    console.log("superman: " + superman);
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve it simply change the state of the child checkbox and change the value of a `superman` variable, but for some reason it always  prints out `superman: false` in the console log. Even when I manually check the checkbox and click the div, even though the checkbox is now checked, it reports `superman: false`

What could be causing this?

Comment: `checked` is a property and should be set using `prop('checked',true)`

Comment: Have a look at the `prop` method in JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/prop/  Also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr for an in-depth discussion of the difference between the two.

Comment: You are reimplementing what the browser already does. Why don't you just use a `<label>` instead of a `<div>`, and then listen for when the checkbox changes, `$("#superman").on("change", fn);` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* just change the `<div>` to `<label>` and get rid of all the jQuery code and it will just work.

Comment: I completely forgot the labels change the state of the checkbox. I'll try that bit now

Comment: You responded too quickly! ;) I have to wait another 5 minutes to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `.prop()` instead of attr as `checked` is property of checkboxes. also you can narrow down your code to:

```
$('#superman').on('click', function () {
 var chk = $(this).find('input:checkbox:first')
 chk.prop("checked", !chk.prop("checked"));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uqy4uyzd/)**

Comment: Thing is - I already tried that one, but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I know, I know, I don't know if it's one of the external libraries or something, I'm not saying it doesn't work at all, I'm just saying it didn't work for me. That's why I came here - to see if there are any other solutions I could take.

Comment: @NemanjaT: can only help if you could reproduce the problem in fiddle/codepen

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#superman').on('click', function () {
    superman = !$(this).children('input:checkbox:first').is(':checked');
    $(this).children('input:checkbox:first').prop('checked',superman);
    console.log("superman: " + superman);
});
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.